# Azure Function Blob Trigger : Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Azure Blob Triggered Function shows following error :

"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Here is a sample function :

```
 [FunctionName("FunctionDemo")]
    public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "blobconn:blob")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    }
```

Here is the connection string in local.settings.json:

[image]

When I run the function locally, I get following error :

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the local.settings.json code in the question how you provided the connection string format - unable to see clearly from the image.

Comment: I used visual studio wizard to create and configure the blob azure function which saved the connection in secret.json file. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: If it solved, please post the resolution how you solved it so that it would be helpful to other community members.